# Using winexe to run "wmic" commands on a Windows machine

Tags: linux, windows, remote

We use winexe to execute commands on our Windows machines from Linux.  For example:

```
winexe -A authfile //syspc4.domain.com "ipconfig /all"
```

Expectedly the above prints out the same thing as if you had run cmd.exe on a Windows machine and typed in "ipconfig /all"

My ultimate goal is to remotely (from Linux) get the Window's machines serial number and model name.  This is very easily achievable with the following two commands in cmd.exe locally on the Windows (Windows XP) machine:

```
wmic bios get serialnumber
wmic computersystem get model
```

However, any attempts to execute this via winexe simply do not work --- after hitting enter, nothing happens.  No error, nothing.  It will just appear to be frozen until I ctrl+c out of it.

Here are the commands that I've tried:

```
winexe -A authfile //syspc4.domain.com "wmic bios get serialnumber"
winexe -A authfile //syspc4.domain.com "cmd wmic bios get serialnumber"
winexe -A authfile //syspc4.domain.com "cmd /c wmic bios get serialnumber"
winexe -A authfile //syspc4.domain.com "cmd"
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>wmic bios get serialnumber
```

In all cases, no response.  A quick look at winexe --help reveals a log option, but even with that set, there is no output log of any kind.

I found the following post on another forum, in which the person is asking almost the *exact* same thing as me, and naturally he just never got an answer: 
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/winexe-780343/

**EDIT**: With debug turned on, this is where it hangs:

```
winexe -d 6 -A authfile //syspc4.domain.com "wmic bios get serialnumber"

...
IN: async_open(\pipe\ahexec, 2)
IN: async_open_recv
CTRL: Sending command: get version
CTRL: Sending command: run wmic bios get serialnumber
CTRL: Recieved command: std_io_err 15C40030
IN: async_open(\pipe\ahexec_stdin15C40030, 2)
IN: async_open(\pipe\ahexec_stdout15C40030, 2)
IN: async_open(\pipe\ahexec_stderr15C40030, 2)
IN: async_open_recv
IN: async_open_recv
IN: async_open_recv

**hangs forever here**

Then ctrl+c:

^CAborting...
ERROR: smb_raw_read_recv - NT_STATUS_PIPE_DISCONNECTED
ERROR: smb_raw_read_recv - NT_STATUS_PIPE_DISCONNECTED
ERROR: smb_raw_read_recv - NT_STATUS_PIPE_DISCONNECTED
ERROR: smb_raw_read_recv - NT_STATUS_PIPE_DISCONNECTED
ERROR: on_ctrl_pipe_error - NT_STATUS_PIPE_DISCONNECTED
```

However the curious thing is that even with a command that doesn't fail (like ipconfig /all), it gives the exact same thing:

```
...
IN: async_open(\pipe\ahexec, 2)
IN: async_open_recv
CTRL: Sending command: get version
CTRL: Sending command: run ipconfig /all
CTRL: Recieved command: std_io_err 15C40031
IN: async_open(\pipe\ahexec_stdin15C40031, 2)
IN: async_open(\pipe\ahexec_stdout15C40031, 2)
IN: async_open(\pipe\ahexec_stderr15C40031, 2)
IN: async_open_recv
IN: async_open_recv
IN: async_open_recv

Windows IP Configuration
...
ERROR: smb_raw_read_recv - NT_STATUS_PIPE_DISCONNECTED
ERROR: smb_raw_read_recv - NT_STATUS_PIPE_DISCONNECTED
ERROR: smb_raw_read_recv - NT_STATUS_PIPE_DISCONNECTED
ERROR: smb_raw_read_recv - NT_STATUS_PIPE_DISCONNECTED
ERROR: on_ctrl_pipe_error - NT_STATUS_PIPE_DISCONNECTED
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, unfortunately I never did.  The answer below for WMI-Client looks promising.  Unfortunately we needed the solution around the time of posting, and ultimately just ended up doing the work by hand.

Comment: I compiled the new winexe from git yesterday (it says version 1.1) and get the exact same errors and issue with it waiting with it requiring to press enter to continue the script.

Comment: This seems to be a recently reopened bug that the devs are at least aware of: https://sourceforge.net/p/winexe/bugs/31/?page=1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the WMI-Client here: http://www.orvant.com/packages/ and run the WMIC commands directly from Linux, although you will have to use the WQL equivalents of your commands, as this version does not support the non-WQL queryies.

Comment: My use for this has long passed, but it looks promising.  I'll mark it as the answer.  If some poor soul years from now finds this via Google and it doesn't work, please leave a comment about your experience/whether it really worked or not.

Comment: I am trying out wmi-client (if I can ever get it to compile on Arch Linux). I'll post back my results.

Answer (score 1):

The latest winexe code (from the "current" git repository, a.k.a. "winexe-waf"; date November 2013) doesn't hang when I test it. I build winexe on Debian Wheezy with Samba 4.0.10 packages from Unstable and run `winexe -U "<user>%<pwd>" //192.168.1.2 'wmic bios get serialnumber'` where 192.168.1.2 is the IP address of a VirtualBox virtual machine running Windows 7 Professional SP1. Output is as follows.

```
$ winexe -U "<user>%<pwd>" //192.168.1.2 'wmic bios get serialnumber'
SerialNumber
0

$ winexe -U "<user>%<pwd>" //192.168.1.2 'wmic computersystem get model'
Model
VirtualBox
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try those command with `winexe`'s debug switch turned on. You can turn up the debug level (looks to be a number such as 0,1,2,3,etc.).

#### Example

Here I'm just running your command as is except I've added the switch `-d 3`.

```
$ winexe -A authfile -d 3 //syspc4.domain.com "wmic bios get serialnumber"

ERROR: Unable to open credentials file!
[param/loadparm.c:587:init_globals()] Initialising global parameters
[param/loadparm.c:2462:lp_load()] lp_load: refreshing parameters from /dev/null
[param/params.c:556:pm_process()] params.c:pm_process() - Processing configuration file "/dev/null"
[param/loadparm.c:1343:lp_add_hidden()] adding hidden service IPC$
[param/loadparm.c:1343:lp_add_hidden()] adding hidden service ADMIN$
[auth/credentials/credentials_krb5.c:171:cli_credentials_set_ccache()] failed to get principal from default ccache: No such file or directory: open(/tmp/krb5cc_500): No such file or directory
[winexe/winexe.c:304:main()] winexe version 0.80
This program may be freely redistributed under the terms of the GNU GPL
[auth/auth.c:447:auth_register()] AUTH backend 'winbind_samba3' registered
[auth/auth.c:447:auth_register()] AUTH backend 'winbind' registered
[auth/auth.c:447:auth_register()] AUTH backend 'name_to_ntstatus' registered
[auth/auth.c:447:auth_register()] AUTH backend 'fixed_challenge' registered
[auth/auth.c:447:auth_register()] AUTH backend 'unix' registered
[auth/auth.c:447:auth_register()] AUTH backend 'anonymous' registered
[auth/auth.c:447:auth_register()] AUTH backend 'sam' registered
[auth/auth.c:447:auth_register()] AUTH backend 'sam_ignoredomain' registered
[auth/gensec/gensec.c:1229:gensec_register()] GENSEC backend 'krb5' registered
[auth/gensec/gensec.c:1205:gensec_register()] gensec subsystem fake_gssapi_krb5 is disabled
[auth/gensec/gensec.c:1229:gensec_register()] GENSEC backend 'schannel' registered
[auth/gensec/gensec.c:1229:gensec_register()] GENSEC backend 'spnego' registered
[auth/gensec/gensec.c:1205:gensec_register()] gensec subsystem gssapi_spnego is disabled
[auth/gensec/gensec.c:1229:gensec_register()] GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5' registered
[auth/gensec/gensec.c:1229:gensec_register()] GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5_sasl' registered
[auth/gensec/gensec.c:1229:gensec_register()] GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp' registered
[lib/util/util.c:334:interpret_addr()] sys_gethostbyname: Unknown host. syspc4.domain.com
[lib/socket/interface.c:103:add_interface()] added interface ip=192.168.1.110 nmask=255.255.255.0
[winexe/winexe.c:322:main()] ERROR: Failed to open connection - NT_STATUS_NO_MEMORY
```

Comment: Ahhhh, it looks for a number!  LOL.  I tried words like "high".  I'll give that a shot!

Comment: @CptSupermrkt - yes isn't it nice when they provide you with a program and a usage page but no man page that spells the actual details of how to "really" use it.

Comment: @CptSupermrkt - The RPM that provides that package doesn't include a cent of documentation either. Nice 8-(.

Comment: @CptSupermrkt - I have to ask, what's Captain Supermarket?

Comment: I updated my question with the output of debug.  Captain Supermarket is the Japanese title of the movie "Army of Darkness" :)

Comment: @CptSupermrkt - WTF? Are you serious? Thanks I'm crying from laughter.

Comment: @CptSupermrkt - There is a slight difference. Works = 15C40031 vs. doesn't work = 15C40030.

Comment: Hah...you're right!  LOL.  That's funny.  If it comes down to that being my one and only clue, I might just let this slide and abandon this part of the project as it's not vital for what I'm doing, just a "would be nice" kinda thing.

Comment: @CptSupermrkt - I think that difference is a red herring but something to go on.

Comment: @CptSupermrkt - googling it didn't shed any light.

Comment: Same.  Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @CptSupermrkt - the other direction I'd be inclined to go here with is to look for `winexe wmi hang` in google. There are some leads. I have to head home, will pick up when I get there.

Comment: @CptSupermrkt - is it possible that the `wmi` command is sitting at a prompt on the windows side? Check out this technique for using `cat ... | winexe ..` to send bunch of commands to a PC: http://opensourceinfo.blogspot.com/2010/01/winexe.html

Comment: No go.  Thanks though, seriously, don't go too far out of your way on this :)