# How to force PC to release IP?

Tags: dhcp, backtrack, remote-management

I'm working on BackTrack and I want to give a fake IP from my DHCP server to another PC.

I'm trying to make that Windows PC run the command: `ipconfig /release`, but without remote access. I don't want to have to remote into the Windows PC and run `ipconfig /release` manually. I'd like to run this command remotely from my Linux box.

I tried to send DHCP RELEASE packets with the application Yersinia... but it did not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Release a Window's PC's IP

*(Rephrased Question)*

You might be able to use the tool `winexe` to do this.

```
$ winexe -U DOM/USER_NAME  //remotePC "ipconfig /release"
```

#### Release my IP

*(original question)*

The command is `ifconfig <interface>` on Linux.

```
$ sudo ifconfig eth0 down
```

Will bring down the interface. To release you can use `dhclient <interface>` to release the DHCP lease.

```
$ sudo dhclient -r eth0
```

Comment: you misunderstood my question , I don't want to release my IP , I want remotely to release the other pc's IP , but without using remote access , for example : some kind of DOS_attack on ethernet device !!

Comment: @EmadAldeen - you want the DHCP server to release the IP? Or are you trying to remotely induce a release from PC-X to PC-Y?

Comment: forget about the dhcp server ...
here is the scenario : I'm working on X PC , and want Y PC to release its IP .
usually ,you need to go to Y and type : ipconfig release .
but is there and way to do it from X PC ?

Comment: @EmadAldeen - you want to remotely run the command `ipconfig /release` to Y PC (Windows) from X PC (linux)?

Comment: Yes ... Is there anyway ??
I saw a tool called yersinia ... but it is useless ... any ideas please ?

Comment: @EmadAldeen - you might be able to use the command `winexe ... ipconfig /release`. See this Q for and example: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82825/using-winexe-to-run-wmic-commands-on-a-windows-machine

Comment: it worked ... but the Y PC is anonymous ... I don't know anything about it except its IP ... so this tool can't help because it needs username and password .

Comment: @EmadAldeen - I know of no way in except through this method. The only other options are through backdoors, if at all.